# Have to repeatedly press enter for Terminal commands to work -- OS X 10.7.3 Lion

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-lion, terminal.app

I've encountered a very, very strange error. Whenever I type a command, I must press enter several times before the Terminal executes the command. Note that this is not a hardware error: I can still the newlines appear on the screen, but Terminal, for whatever reason, doesn't handle it correctly.

For example, typing "rails server" must be followed by around 4 presses of enter, and the title of the Terminal changes from "bash" to "env" to "ruby" and then to "sh" and then to "ruby" again before anything happens.

Similarly, commands like "git -v" don't even work anymore, as pressing enter somehow aborts them.

Comment: dont know much about osx , but this sounds like a keyboard malfunction , try using another keyboard for the task

Comment: The enter-presses are actually registered in the Terminal, and I can see them appear as normal. My problem is that Terminal is handling these enter-presses in a strange way.

Comment: The first thing to try is running your shell without any customizations. You can do this in Terminal with **Shell > New Command**. If you're using bash (the default shell), run `bash --noprofile`. Then see if the problem remains. Another thing to check for is a customized `~/.inputrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

What is the Keyboard Input Source you using?

I had the same problem when using VNI, switched back to US (In Keyboard Preferences.../Input Sources tab) it was back to normal.